# E-Mail with images from 2 different host, are there problems?

Tags: email, firewall

We send E-Mail which contain images from two different hosts.
In thunderbird / outlook they are displayed fine (after clicking the 'load images' button).

Are there E-Mail Clients (Web-Mail-Clients) which produce problems in this scenario?
Are the "Personal Firewalls" which interfere here?

Thanks
Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal firewalls are unlikely to be an issue at all, unless the host(s) the images are on are blocked generally. I don't know of any clients that would refuse to display images from a range of sources either (a quick scan of the "newsletters" I got from places I buy computer parts from show they use objects from multiple sub-domains in one email). You *may* fall foul of some spam filters though.